# \XC@usec@lor ...\expandafter \c@lor@to@ps #1#2\@@by

Tags: pstricks

I have a LaTex document which I was able successfully to compile until 2014.

Today I am not to compile correctly.

I think the problem is in my package "PSBao.sty" which I never changed.

Unfornately I don't understand what happened.

Can someone help me?

Compiling by different editors this semplified version of my document:

```
\documentclass[
paper=a5,
fontsize=10pt,
DIV=calc,
headsepline,
footsepline,
titlepage,
headings=normal,
version=last,
twoside=true,           % prova eliminazione geometry
headinclude=true,
footinclude=true,
mpinclude=true,
BCOR=1.8cm
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{arabtex}

\usepackage{psbao}

\begin{document}

   \centering
  \setbaounit{.4cm}
  \initbao[0,%
            0,2,5,6,4,2,1,1,%
            0,6,1,5,4,0,2,6,%
            0,0,0,6,1,0,0,0,%
            0,0,3,1,1,0,4,3,%
            0]
  \begin{showbaoboard}
  \end{showbaoboard}

  \vspace{10pt}
  \hspace{0.1\textwidth}
  \vspace{10pt}
   \centering
  \setbaounit{.4cm}
  \initbao[0,%
            0,2,5,6,4,2,1,1,%
            0,6,1,5,4,0,2,6,%
            1,1,1,0,2,1,1,1,%
            1,1,0,2,2,1,0,4,%
            0]
  \begin{showbaoboard}
  \baoarrow{A}{5}
  \end{showbaoboard}

\end{document}
```

I get a lot of following error messages:

```
 ! Undefined control sequence.
 \c@lor@to@ps ->\PSTricks_Not_Configured_For_This_Format
 1.100   \end{showbaoboard}

 ! Undefined control sequence.
 \XC@usec@lor ...\expandafter \c@lor@to@ps #1#2\@@ 
                                                  \else \expandafter \expand...
 l.100   \end
            {showbaoboard}
```

I googled a lot but didn't find any help!

Thank you very much

Comment: You are probably using the wrong engine. Try latex instead of pdflatex.

Comment: Thanks. It works but still with some errors. Anyway can you explain why in 2014 pdflatex worked well and now I have to use latex?

Comment: using pstricks with pdflatex never worked correctly or well, but you didn't get always an error to warn you that you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Do you know a good alternative to pstricks?

Comment: The problem is the command `\baoarrow{A}{5}`

Answer (score 1):

the macro `\baoarrow` is the problem:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{psbao,pst-calculate}

\let\BAOmoves\baomoves
\renewcommand\baomoves{%
  \BAOmoves
  \renewcommand\baoarrow[2]{%
    \conx{##1}{##2}
    \psdots[dotstyle=triangle*,dotscale=2]%
      (\baoyposition{\thetmpc},\pscalculate{0.5*\baoxposition{##1}})
  }%
}

\begin{document}

    \initbao[0,%
    0,2,5,6,4,2,1,1,%
    0,6,1,5,4,0,2,6,%
    1,1,1,0,2,1,1,1,%
    1,1,0,2,2,1,0,4,%
    0]
\begin{showbaoboard}
\baoarrow{A}{5}
\end{showbaoboard}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Run it with `xelatex` or use package `auto-pst-pdf`